# group with multiple ids and sum in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, group-by, sum

```
{
            "_id" : ObjectId("59774aa87da165f360b0271a"),
            "createdDate" : ISODate("2017-07-25T13:42:00.000Z"),
            "sourceId" : ObjectId("000000000000000000000000"),
            "fanClubId" : ObjectId("59774aa87da165f360b02719"),
            "coins" : -500,
            "reasonId" : ObjectId("593500980b0cbbe593cd722c"),
            "userId" : ObjectId("597731d3ee99e33e1696de79")
        }

        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("59784c76e8288e1be6dace64"),
            "createdDate" : ISODate("2017-07-26T08:01:58.000Z"),
            "sourceId" : ObjectId("000000000000000000000000"),
            "fanClubId" : ObjectId("59784c76e8288e1be6dace63"),
            "coins" : -500,
            "reasonId" : ObjectId("593500980b0cbbe593cd722c"),
            "userId" : ObjectId("597731d3ee99e33e1696de79")
        }

        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("597734e376f9e53e0e52588a"),
            "createdDate" : ISODate("2017-07-25T12:09:07.000Z"),
            "sourceId" : ObjectId("000000000000000000000000"),
            "fanClubId" : ObjectId("000000000000000000000000"),
            "coins" : 5,
            "reasonId" : ObjectId("593501ff0b0cbbe593cd7236"),
            "userId" : ObjectId("597731d3ee99e33e1696de79")
        }

        db.getCollection('FanCoins').aggregate([{$group : {_id:{userId:ObjectId("597731d3ee99e33e1696de79"),
        reasonId:ObjectId("593500980b0cbbe593cd722c")},coins:{$sum : { $add: ["$coins"]}}}} ])
```

I used this query to get the result for sum of coins of userId & reasonId, but i'm getting the total sum of userId's. How to do this in mongodb group by.

Comment: You mean `{ "$group": { "_id": { "userId": "$userId", "reasonId": "$reasonId" } , "coins": { "$sum": "$coins" } } }`. You use the `$` prefixed names there to represent the "value" of the fields. When you are supplying `ObjectId(...)` it essentially just groups "everything" and outputs one record with those supplied values, rather than what actually exists in the documents. If you just want a specific combination, then you add a `$match` to filter out only documents that contain those values, and possibly using `$or`.

Comment: There actually are several examples on the main manual page for [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/). Particularly [Group by Month, Day and Year](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/#group-by-month-day-and-year) which demonstrates a common usage for a "compound" grouping key, along with some accumulators.